# Removing repeated characters in String

Tags: java, regex, string

I am having strings like this "aaaabbbccccaaddddcfggghhhh" and i want to remove repeated characters get a string like this "abcadcfgh".

A simplistic implementation for this would be :

```
for(Character c:str.toCharArray()){
  if(c!=prevChar){
    str2.append(c);
    prevChar=c;
  }

}

return str2.toString();
```

Is it possible to have a better implementation may be using regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
"aaaabbbccccaaddddcfggghhhh".replaceAll("(.)\\1+","$1");
```

The regex uses backreference and capturing groups.

The normal regex is `(.)\1+` but you've to escape the backslash by another backslash in java.

If you want number of repeated characters:

```
String test = "aaaabbbccccaaddddcfggghhhh";
System.out.println(test.length() - test.replaceAll("(.)\\1+","$1").length());
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/9NLS4n)

Comment: Thanks Amit, works like charm. One more query, if i want to trim the string as done above and also want total count of repeated character then can regex help ?

Comment: @Lokesh, yes, you can do that, but with a different regex.

Comment: It will be great if you can provide me that as well or give some reference.

Comment: @Lokesh,yes One minute

Answer (score 2):

With regex, you can replace `(.)\1+` with the replacement string `$1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java's **String**.[`replaceAll()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) method to simply do this with a regular expression.

```
String s = "aaaabbbccccaaddddcfggghhhh";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(.)\\1{1,}", "$1")) //=> "abcadcfgh"
```

Regular expression

```
(               group and capture to \1:
 .              any character except \n
)               end of \1
\1{1,}          what was matched by capture \1 (at least 1 times)
```

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern `/(.)(?=\1)/g` and replace with nothing
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eU6aW7)

Comment: SO java implementation would be str.replaceAll("/(.)(?=\1)/g", "")  ?