# App Inventor 2 - Remove repeated letters in a string

Tags: app-inventor

Im trying to make a Vigenère Encrypter and a key in a vigenere cipher should have no repeating letters so how can i remove letters that have already been used in a string?  This is on MIT App Inventor 2

Answer (score 1):

you might want to use a regular expression...
see also these answers [Removing repeated characters in String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23520205/1545993)

for regular expressions in App Inventor, you can use [this extension](https://community.thunkable.com/t/regular-expression-extension/3657?u=taifun) by kevinkun
for a list of extensions, see also here https://puravidaapps.com/extensions.php